# How to clear collections in javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler?

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, listener

I have got 2 `Pane`. The first pane is main menu, there is only `Rectangle` in its `children`. The second pane is my game. When I go to main menu I use following method to clear game pane

```
//Fighting fighting = new Fighting();
//There is Pane fighting in fighting
if(fighting != null) {
    fighting.getFighting().getChildren().clear();
    fighting = null;
    System.gc();
}
```

When I `scene.setRoot(fighting.getFighting());` and don't do anything(don't hover on objects which has `OnMouse...()`, don't call methods which move player) and exit to main menu(by clicking Esc)

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) setFighting();
    if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE) setMainMenu();
});
```

In such case I don't have problems with memory and GC deletes useless objects.

**But if I click/hover on any objects with `listeners` or call `move()` on player, GC won't delete the same object.** And if I re-enter game pane and use it normally, GC will delete objects from prevoius session and won't delete them from current session

In my profiler I've found out that references on these useless objects are stored in `Pane` which is in one of `ArrayList`s in anonymous class `MouseHandler` in `Scene`. Can't add [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZxCC.png) good.

Also I've found out that there are only 2 `Pane` in heap. One of them is `mainMenu`. I've understood it because there is only `Rectangle` in its `children`. And the second's pane's children equals `children.size() == 0`.

It's code from `Scene` & `MouseHandler`

```
private MouseHandler mouseHandler;

class MouseHandler {

   /* lists needed for enter/exit events generation */
    private final List<EventTarget> pdrEventTargets = new ArrayList<EventTarget>();
    private final List<EventTarget> currentEventTargets = new ArrayList<EventTarget>();
    private final List<EventTarget> newEventTargets = new ArrayList<EventTarget>();

    private final List<EventTarget> fullPDRCurrentEventTargets = new ArrayList<EventTarget>();
    private final List<EventTarget> fullPDRNewEventTargets = new ArrayList<EventTarget>();
    private EventTarget fullPDRCurrentTarget = null;

}
```

Is it possible to clear these collections or to fix memory leak? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

Well technically you may use the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to get access to that list and clear it manually, but i’m not sure would it be safe to do so.

AFAIK that `pdrEventTargets` list is holding components chain that represents a path from the scene to a component that was clicked the last and that list is being refreshed at each click. So if you’re in situation when you have replaced a branch of componens tree and still seeing a bunch of references on removed components in that list, these are will be removed from `pdrEventTargets` on the next click handling by `MouseHandler`. At least it behaves exactly like that while i debugging at jdk 1.8. Probably you have exactly the same behavior, so there should be no reasons to worry about, at least if these staled components do not holding a references to some “heavy” objects that should not live after these components was removed. In that case you should remove that references as part of the process of components remove.

Comment: Really good answer, in case if pane carrying a lot of data, in my case gigabytes, and there is no interaction from user, overflow is very near, so reflection is the only way to get around. Although really strange behavior not to release resources immediately after they are removed from managed views.